# Artisan command says : Dotenv values containing spaces must be surrounded by quotes

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-artisan

I'm trying to know the list of artisan command by using `php artisan list` . and the command return me the following error 
`[Dotenv\Exception\InvalidFileException]
  Dotenv values containing spaces must be surrounded by quotes.`
What is wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Some `.env` libraries are picky about the syntax (or you simply got it wrong). You should check your `.env` file.

Answer (score 103, accepted):

You should remove all spaces from `.env` file to make an app work again.

If you have to use spaces, instead of this:

```
VAR=some data
```

Use quotes:

```
VAR="some data"
```

Comment: I had a block comment `/* */` that was causing this error. The value was quoted, so I thought the comment would not be an issue, but it was. Replaced it with `#` and it worked.

Answer (score 10):

Verify your .env file. You need to check for the following:

- Any extra or non-needed spaces
- If you have any strings with spaces, make sure to surround them in quotes

Example:

```
varaible=123 Test
```

Needs to be

```
varaible="123 Test"
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that:

- all variables with spaces are surrounded by quotes
- there are no semi-colons

Answer (score 0):

if you use two word for username or database name in .env,put it inside a double quotation.

[image: example]

Answer (score 0):

> First check env.
>
> If your var value with space so check value in double quotes. like,

```
 MAIL_FROM_NAME="Sarvajanik School"
```

If you use single quotes then the possible to got this error **containing spaces must be surrounded by quotes**