# How do I hide my discord bot token when I upload its code on github?

Tags: git

I'm coding this discordbot and want it to be on github. How can I upload it without making its token public?

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();
// Following is the part that matter, the code before is just to get some context 
const token = '[hidden for security reasons]';
```

I think I should put it on a separate file, but I don't know how to reference it on my index.js file.

How do I solve the problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are many ways to get secret info out of your code.

The easiest is probably to use environment variables.
You could e.g. use this in your code:

```
const token = process.env.DISCORD_TOKEN;
```

And then set the env variable before calling your script (assuming bash shell):

```sh
DISCORD_TOKEN=1234foobar1234 node myscript.js
```

To simplify this you could use a package like [`dotenv`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv):

```
require('dotenv').config();

const token = process.env.DISCORD_TOKEN;
```

Then you can create a `.env` file in your project root directory:
`.env`:

```
DISCORD_TOKEN=1234foobar1234
```

(remember to add this file to `.gitignore` to avoid accidental commits)

Comment: It's definitely doing what it's supposed to do, but it keep saying that the login credentials provided are invalid. Any idea why is this happening?

Comment: @innis if your credentials contain spaces or other funny characters you need to [quote them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43639440/artisan-command-says-dotenv-values-containing-spaces-must-be-surrounded-by-quo)

Comment: @innis if you run a `console.log(process.env.DISCORD_TOKEN);` does it output the correct value?

Comment: sorry, I was picking the wrong token. it's working now